# R foreach+doMC tasks not returning any results for large data frames

Tags: r, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop that parallelizes some computation over a large dataset. Each worker writes its output to a file and returns NULL to the parent process.

For this reason the `foreach` loop uses a dummy combiner, which simply ignores all the outputs from the workers. Strangely, this works fine for small- to moderate-sized data frames, but not for large ones.

Concretely, my data.table, say **dt**, consists of **7'237'605** rows and **5'993** unique ids. Each worker is supposed to take one id and do something with its corresponding data.

The actual loop is given below:

```
unique_ids = unique(dt$id)

registerDoMC(40)
foreach(i=unique_ids,
      .options.multicore=list(preschedule=TRUE),
      .export=c('cfun'),
      .combine='cfun', .multicombine=TRUE, .maxcombine = 3000,
      .inorder=FALSE, .verbose = TRUE) %dopar%  
      {

        DT = dt[id==i]

        # do something with DT and write output to file
        # ...
        # ...
        # finished writing to file

        0 # return 0 or NULL, doesn't really matter, we don't care
      }
```

The combiner function ignores everything (taken from the foreach vignette):

```
cfun = function(...) {NULL}
```

At the end of the day, all I care about are the files outputted from each worker.

As mentioned before, this works fine on smaller datasets, for example with **4'009'012** rows and again **5'993** unique ids. The output of .verbose is as expected:

```
numValues: 4993, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
setting mc.preschedule option to 1
```

and then after all tasks have completed:

```
got results for task 1
numValues: 4993, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE
got results for task 2
numValues: 4993, numResults: 2, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE

...

got results for task 4993
numValues: 4993, numResults: 4993, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE

evaluating call object to combine results:
    fun(accum, result.3001, result.3002, ... result.4993)
returning status TRUE
```

This happens almost instantenously, so that I get control over the main R process very fast after all workers are done (in other words, no costs for combining the results)

However with the large data.table, the process gets stuck at:

```
numValues: 4993, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
setting mc.preschedule option to 1
```

Even after the tasks complete, nothing is sent to the parent process and there is no collection of results taking place.

How can I debug / rectify this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turned out that the part where I "do something with DT and write output to file" had a bug in it, which led to the process getting stuck in an endless loop. Once that was fixed, it all worked fine.

This was not a `foreach` or `doMC` related question after all.